# How to implement a for loop in a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have been tasked to create a `pig_latin` method.

> Pig Latin is a made-up children's language that's intended to be
>    confusing. It obeys a few simple rules (below) but when it's spoken
>    quickly it's really difficult for non-children (and non-native
>    speakers) to understand.
>
> Rule 1: If a word begins with a vowel sound, add an "ay" sound to
>    the end of the word.
>
> Rule 2: If a word begins with a consonant sound, move it to the end
>    of the word, and then add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.
>
> (There are a few more rules for edge cases, and there are regional
>   variants too, but that should be enough to understand the tests.)

All my tests are passing save one, to translate many words.

This is my error:

```
#translate
  translates a word beginning with a vowel
  translates a word beginning with a consonant
  translates a word beginning with two consonants
  translates two words
  translates a word beginning with three consonants
  counts 'sch' as a single phoneme
  counts 'qu' as a single phoneme
  counts 'qu' as a consonant even when it's preceded by a consonant
  translates many words (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) #translate translates many words
     Failure/Error: expect(s).to eq("ethay ickquay ownbray oxfay")

       expected: "ethay ickquay ownbray oxfay"
            got: "ethay"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/04_pig_latin_spec.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00236 seconds (files took 0.10848 seconds to load)
9 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/04_pig_latin_spec.rb:68 # #translate translates many words
```

And this is my method:

```
def translate(str)

  def add_ay(str)
   return str + 'ay'
  end

  def word_begins_with_vowel(str)
    if (!(str.match(' '))) && $vowels[str[0]]
      return add_ay(str)
    end     
  end

  def begins_with_consonant(str)
    if ((!$vowels[str[0]]) && (!$vowels[str[1]]) && (!$vowels[str[2]])) 
      first_three = str.split('').slice(0, 3).join('');
      str = str.slice(3, str.length - 1)
      return str +  first_three + 'ay'
    end
    if ((!$vowels[str[0]]) && (!$vowels[str[1]])) 
      first_two = str.split('').slice(0, 2).join('');
      str = str.slice(2, str.length - 1)
      return str +  first_two + 'ay'
    end
    if ((!$vowels[str[0]]))
     first_char = str.split('').slice(0);
     str = str.slice(1, str.length - 1)
     return str + first_char +'ay'
    end
  end

  def translates_two_words(str)
    if (str.match(' '))
      str = str.split(' ');
      first_char = str[1].split('').slice(0);
      str[1] = str[1].slice!(1, str[1].length - 1);

      return str[0] + 'ay' + ' ' + str[1] + first_char + 'ay'
    end     
  end

  def translates_many_words(str)
      str = str.split(' ');
      if str.length > 2
        str.each do |item| 
          return begins_with_consonant(item) || word_begins_with_vowel(item)
        end
      end
  end

  $vowels = {
    'a' => add_ay(str),
    'e' => add_ay(str), 
    'i' => add_ay(str), 
    'o' => add_ay(str), 
    'y' => add_ay(str)
  }
    return translates_many_words(str) || word_begins_with_vowel(str) || begins_with_consonant(str) || translates_two_words(str)
end
```

I would figure this would take care of many words:

```
def translates_many_words(str)
      str = str.split(' ');
      if str.length > 2
        str.each do |item| 
          return begins_with_consonant(item) || word_begins_with_vowel(item)
        end
      end
  end
```

but it's not.

Comment: `str.each... return` will return on the first value in the first iteration, so iterating will not do what you want. It's not idiomatic to embed all your methods inside a wrapping method.

Comment: for the first look, to make your test passes - `str.map { |item| begins_with_consonant(item) || word_begins_with_vowel(item) }.join(' ')`

Comment: @AlexGolubenko Thanks pal! Could you please add your solution in the context or display what ya mean? Appreciate it!

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz I'll recommend you to check UPD of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @theTinMan says, `return` - will decline next iteration and just return the first value in the first iteration, from my comment, I think, this should work for you(with minimum editing of your code):

```
def translates_many_words(str)
  str = str.split(' ');

  if str.length > 2
    str.map do |item| 
      begins_with_consonant(item) || word_begins_with_vowel(item)
    end.join(' ')
  end
end
```

**UPD** 
Also, I'll recommend you to refactor your code to make it more readable, it could help you in the future.
My variant of this method is:

```
def translates_many_words(str)
  str = str.split

  # line under - is a shortcut from `return nil if str.size <= 2`
  # `#size` is more relative to this context if you will count elements of array 
  return unless str.size > 2 

  # Now, when we excluded possibility of work with array that have less then 2 elements, 
  # we can continue with our iteration
  str.map do |item| 
    begins_with_consonant(item) || word_begins_with_vowel(item)
  end.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: `;` at line ends are not necessary, nor are the idiomatic. `split(' ')` can be written `split` as its default behavior is to split on whitespace.

Comment: @theTinMan your right, but, as I say: "with minimum editing of your code", in the UPD, you can saw my variant)

Comment: Instead of using "UPD" or "update" or "edit", simply add the information where it'd have gone if you'd included it originally. SO maintains revision control of all questions and answers, so we can see what changed and when if we need to. Clarity and readability are much more important than notating every week and change.